# Batch file split a string?

Tags: batch-file

I've tried

```
for /F "delims= " %%A in ("Hello World") do echo %%A %%B
```

and it says

```
Hello
%B
```

I need to get %%A and %%B to be 'hello' and 'world' but what I've tried above doesn't work. What do I need to do? I've tried without "delims= " and without /F and it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

you need also `tokens` option:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in ("Hello World") do echo %%A %%B
```

and `1` will become `%%A` and the second token corresponds to `%%B`.In this case the out put will be "Hello Earth":

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%A in ("Hello planet Earth") do echo %%A %%C
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to specify the tokens (Default is "tokens=1", so `%%b` is not valid with your code):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ("hello world") do echo %%a-%%b
```

the shorter version without `/f` is:

```
for %%i in (hello world) do echo %%i
```

Comment: Just commenting:  the shorter version will use a line for each word though.

Comment: ...which might be an advantage, if you want to set  the substrings into variables or don't know how many substrings there are.

Comment: Depending on the extent of the list or code, you may do well to add a: `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` YMMV...